# How does Raspbian OS store time during power outage in Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, linux, raspbian-stretch

I have Raspberry Pi 3 computer with 'RASPBIAN STRETCH LITE' OS on it.
The computer does not have any real time clock and cannot preserve time during a power outage. However when I unplug power from the computer it preserves time somewhere.

Here are my questions:

1. How does Raspbian OS store time during power outage in Raspberry Pi
   3?
2. When does it update stored value?

Here is an example of short test that shows that the computer stores time:

1. Unplug Ethernet cable and unplug power cable.
2. Plug power cable back.

Actual result: The time on the computer does not reset to something like 'January 1, 2010'. It resets to a time that is only 20-30 minutes behind my current time.

3. Restart the computer again by unplugging the power cable.
   The time resets back to the same value that was seen at step 2.

Comment: See https://packages.debian.org/unstable/main/fake-hwclock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the file /etc/fake-hwclock.data is periodically updated with the latest date/time as the Pi runs.  When the Pi restarts the time is set from this file unless a network time or a RTC time is available.

This ensures that file date time stamps are always reasonably correct.